# Best solution to resolve toLowerCase() null pointer exception in RecylcerView Search

Tags: android, search, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

So, I filter a RecylerView using the following code.  It works fine.  I'm happy with how it responds.

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            List<TrailsObject> list_queryResults =new ArrayList<>();

            String charString = (constraint ==null) ? "" : constraint.toString();
            if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                list_queryResults = list_main;
            }else{
                for (TrailsObject trailsObject : list_main) {
                    if (trailsObject.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)
                            || trailsObject.getSummary().toLowerCase().contains(charString)
                            || trailsObject.getType().toLowerCase().contains(charString)
                            || trailsObject.getLocation().toLowerCase().contains(charString)
                    )
                    list_queryResults.add(trailsObject);
                }
            }
            filterResults.values = list_queryResults;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            listFiltered_main = (List<TrailsObject>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

If a rogue field (`Name`, `Summary`, `Type`, `Location`) is null, the `toLowerCase()` will throw `NPE`.  This has yet to happen, but seems possible.  I have no control over this database.

What is my best course of action to resolve that?  I could do a null check for each field each iteration (seems expensive).  I wonder if I can add a try catch block around the `for loop` somehow.  I am truly open to suggestion.

Comment: you may add something like `containsSummary(String compare)` mathod to your `trailsObject` class, which will check `Summary` for null before `.contains()`, and same for other fields

Answer (score 0):

If you can use java 8.
It's has the [Java.util.optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class that helps in exactly these situations.
Read [this](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html).

In case you can't or don't want to use it you can use [Google guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) optional that does almost the same.